# Migrate Classic Calendar to Modern

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calendar, calendar-view

I have sites in SharePoint Online where the calendars are implemented using the "classic" calendar.

I also have some newer calendars that are implemented in the new experience where you use any list and set the date fields when you create the view.  Some users would like to migrate to the newer style.

This feels like such a simple request, but I don't see any option. The sites are all modern.

Am I missing a simple solution, or do I need to delete and recreate the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly switch the classic calendar list to the modern custom list in SharePoint.

If you are creating a new modern list & calendar view, you have to migrate all data from old list to new list, either manually or using any migration tool.

---

However, for your requirements, you can follow this workaround I tried on my SharePoint site:

**Switch list experience to modern**:

1. Go to calendar list settings > Advanced Settings
2. Select list experience to "New experience".

   [image]
3. Click "OK

**Create new modern calendar view in list**:

1. Go to "All Items" view of list using URL in this format: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/listName/AllItems.aspx`
2. Create a modern calendar view in list by following this article: [Create a modern Calendar view in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)

**Set newly created view as a default view**:

1. Go to newly created calendar view (I created new view with name - "ModernCalendar"):

   [image]
2. Click on "Switch view options" dropdown again from modern calendar view and select "Set current view as default":

   [image]

---

**Note**:

1. If above workaround is not working for you, you have to create a new modern custom list, create a calendar view and then migrate data from old list to new list
2. Modern calendar view do not support all features of classic calendar lists. For example recurring events and calendar overlays. For other limitations, check comments section of article: [Create a modern Calendar view in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)

Comment: I hate that this is the answer.  It feels non-sensical that the old calendars, which are indeed lists, can't be converted to the new format where you are supposed to be able to easily add a calendar view to any list with dates.  I'm sure that there is a good reason behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, there is currently no way to directly switch the calendar in the classic view to the calendar in the modern view you mentioned.
Here is a workaround for your reference:
You can use the Insert Events web part in a modern Page to display Calendar application events.
**Note: Categories from the original calendar must be filled in.**
Add an Events web part to a site page.
[image: Add an Events web part to a site page]

Source select "**This site**" or "**Events list on this site**". Other settings can refer to the picture below.
[image: Source select]

The result:
[image: result]

When you click **"Add event"**,It will display:
[image]

====================
If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.